# PHP mysqli binding parameter from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, bindparam

I use this function to bind parameters into prepared statement ,
the parameters are a string inside `$_POST["params"]` and it looks like that:

```
{type1:value1}{type2:value2}....
```

This function is supposed to bind each param with the statement but i get errors :

```
function executeQuery($q)
 {
   global $server,$user,$pwd,$db,$output;
   $cn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pwd);
   mysqli_set_charset($cn,"utf8");
   mysqli_select_db($cn,$db);
   if(isset($_POST["params"]))
   {
    $ps = mysqli_prepare($cn,base64_decode($q));
    $params = $_POST["params"];
    $params_array = array();
    while(strlen($params)>0)
    {
        $n1 = strpos($params,"{");
        $n2 = strpos($params,"}'");

        $param = substr($params,$n1+1,$n2-($n1+1));
        $param_exploded = explode(":",$param);
        $type = $param_exploded[0];
        $params_array[$param_exploded [1]] = $param_exploded[1];
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($ps,$type,$params_array[$param_exploded[1]]);
        if($n2+1>=strlen($params))
            break;
        $params = substr($params,$n2+1);
    }
    $ps->execute();
    $result = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($ps);
    $count = mysqli_num_fields($result);
    $output.="<table><tr>"; 
   for($i =0;$i<$count;$i++)
   {
    $output.="<th>".mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i)->name."</th>";
   }
  $output.="</tr>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $output.="<tr>";
    for($i =0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $output.="<td>".$row[mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result,$i)->name].</td>";
    }
    $output.="</tr>";
  }
  $output.="</table>";
}
```

The output will be an html table.
P.S :

query

```
select * from t1 where c1 = ? and c2 = ?
```

value of `$_POST["params"]`:

```
"{s:A}{s:N}"
```

Comment: How are you building your post? There may be a better way to get that information.

Comment: @aynber i send post via c# application

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting?

Comment: @MattRink  mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement and Invalid type or no types specified and Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables and Undefined offset